# SimpleAdapter needs an _id field

Tags: android, sqlite

I got this :

`Cursor c = db.query("Org", null, null, null, null, null, null);`

which means I choose a table "Org", but together with this I need to make this :

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT "+ id + " AS _id")
```

because SimpleAdapter need to have an `_id` field necessarily for some reason or it will crash with an error. How do I combine this 2 into one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your statement : `Cursor c = db.query("Org", null, null, null, null, null, null);` the second parameter is wrong, you shoukd mention the column names in it.

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

Whereas for,

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT "+ id + " AS _id from Org");
```

means that you Select `id`  and create an alias of it using `AS` into `_id`, and you are selecting this `id` `from` `Org` table.
so now you will be able to access the result from this query from the column name `_id`, and in order to access the result use:

```
c.moveToFirst();    
while (c.moveToNext())
{
 System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")); 
}
```

Comment: While your answer is almost self-explanatory, could you add a couple of words to highlight how it helps ?

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the [query function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the list of columns.
If you want to rename a column, you cannot just blindy return all columns but have to list the desired columns:

```java
String[] columns = new String[] { id+" AS _id", "Name", "Color", "whatever..." };
Cursor c = db.query("Org", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```